# Como definir classe de página ativa em um cabeçalho incluído em todas as páginas?

Tags: php

Meu site tem um cabeçalho que é chamado em todas as páginas internas com a função `include` do php. Acontece que gostaria de ter a `class="active"` na página que está ativa. Como fazer isso se só tenho um cabeçalho para todas as páginas internas? Estou utilizando bootstrap 3.

Comment: Por favor, adicione um código de exemplo da sua página e especifique como funciona a navegação entre páginas do seu site, para poder gerar uma resposta focada no seu problema, senão a resposta pode ser muito abrangente.

Answer (score 2):

Uma abordagem seria utilizar o seguinte nas suas páginas:

```
$menuAtivo = 'identificador_menu_ativo'; // o identificador deve ser modificado de acordo com a página (inicio, cadastro, listagem por exemplo)
include 'cabecalho.php';
```

Você pode utilizar o código acima em todas as páginas, inserindo uma variável para identificar o item do menu antes de incluir o cabeçalho. Dentro do cabecalho.php, você pode usar algo do tipo:

```
<ul>
    <li <?php echo $menuAtivo == 'inicio' ? 'class="ativo"' : '' ?> > Início </li>
    <li <?php echo $menuAtivo == 'cadastro' ? 'class="ativo"' : '' ?> > Cadastro </li>
    <li <?php echo $menuAtivo == 'listagem' ? 'class="ativo"' : '' ?> > Listagem </li>
</ul>
```